# The inverse of the differential of f inverse

Tags: differential-geometry, inverse-function, diffeomorphism

If I have a diffeomorphism $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$, where $S_1, S_2$ are regular surfaces, then is $(df)^{-1}=df^{-1}$?

How would I show this? I saw a hint that said to consider $f^{-1}\circ f=id$ at some point, but I dont know how the chain rule would reveal the answer.

Comment: The chain rule?

Comment: Sorry, when you differentiate both sides.

Comment: I presume that differentiating the $id$ you get $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to take the differentiation rule for inverse functions:
As

$$ f^{-1}\circ f = id $$
we have
$$ E = d(f^{-1}\circ f) = (df^{-1})\circ f \cdot d f $$
As $df$ is regular we thus get
$$ (df)^{-1} = (df^{-1})\circ f $$

Comment: What are you representing with E, and what does $df$ being regular mean? Thanks.

Comment: Although I totally agree with you proof, I find your notations quite confusing. Never ever heard of "$E$" as a notation for the identity map of the tangent bundle, and $(df \circ f^{-1})d f$ may look weird to people that encounter difficulties with the chain rule

Comment: @Didier Yes, notation is hard because we have different maps. We both have maps between $S_1,S_2$ and between tangent spaces, where $E$ should be the identity map on the tangent space, which is a different map then the identity on the surface. Maybe a better way to write this would be
$$ d_{f(p)}f^{-1} \circ f_p f $$
or something.

Comment: @tymorr $E$ is the identity map on the tangent space. $df$ regular means that $df$ is invertible in any point, so in some sense that it’s image preserves the rank of the tangent space.

Comment: @Lazy I guess writing $$ \forall p \in S_1,\quad  d_{f(p)}(f^{-1}) \circ d_pf = Id$$ is less confusing